# Dual monitor setup with Ubuntu 11.04 not working

Tags: hdmi, vga, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-11.04

First, I should say that the secondary monitor is a 19-inch TV that only has HDMI inputs. My laptop only supports VGA output, so I have a VGA cable connected to a VGA-to-HDMI adapter, with an HDMI cable going into the TV. This setup works fine in Windows 7.

However, in Ubuntu 11.04 Classic, when I go to System --> Preferences --> Monitors, a secondary monitor is not recognized.

My graphics card is a 512 MB NVIDIA NVS 3100m.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in that adapter. If you somehow connect it HDMI-HDMI, it is recognized, and works fine.

You may change your `xorg.config` file, to set the right display. Auto Recognize won't work.